# Using NSDate as Unique Identifier in NSDefaults

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsuserdefaults

I'm having an issue where I'm setting a NSUserDefault key to my "currentDate" but it's value seems to be 4 seconds later then the value that's being stored in CoreData. I'm using the same 'currentDate' NSDate value as seen in the code below. I assume it's because it's grabbing the datepickers current date all over again 4 seconds after when it's saving the NSUserDefaults? How would I fix this?

```
CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
EventEntry *entry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EventEntry" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext];
entry.title = self.titleField.text;
entry.date = self.datePicker.date.timeIntervalSinceNow;
[coreDataStack saveContext];
//Create the dateformatter object
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

//Set the required date format
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"];

NSCalendar *calender = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDate *currentDate = self.datePicker.date;
NSLog(@"Todays date is %@",[formatter stringFromDate:currentDate]);

NSDateComponents *dateComp = [NSDateComponents new];
notificationTime = -notificationTime;
[dateComp setMinute:notificationTime];
[dateComp setSecond:0];
NSDate *targetDate = [calender dateByAddingComponents:dateComp toDate:currentDate options:0];
NSLog(@"Local Notification is set for %@",[formatter stringFromDate:targetDate]);
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = targetDate;
localNotification.alertBody = @"Testing Local Notification";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];


formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
NSLog(@"Date String Key: %@", dateString);
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:localNotification];
[userDefaults setObject:data forKey:dateString];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the same date for your managed object and the user default key.

Instead, you should use `currentDate`.

```
entry.date = currentDate;
```

Comment: entry.date is a NSTimeInterval which is why it's converted, however I even tried moving NSDate *currentDate = self.datePicker.date; above entry.date = currentDate; and changing it to entry.date = currentDate.timeIntervalSinceNow; and still no luck.

Comment: Why are you not saving the date as a date? With the picker date and the time interval since the moveable target "now" you have two data points of which one is unnecessary.